# when the button is clicked i want the multiple selected checkbox row to be displayed from popup page to parent page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

i have a table when the table row is selected.i want that particular row to be appended in another table.

```
  <table class="myTable" border="1">
       <tr class="table">
            <th class="table">
               ID
            </th>
            <th class="table">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="table">
                Price
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table">
            <td class="table">
                1
            </td>
            <td class="table">
                A
            </td>
            <td class="table">
                1500
            </td>
             <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table">
            <td class="table">
                2
            </td>
            <td class="table">
                B
            </td>
            <td class="table">
                3455
            </td>
              <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="">
            </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="printTable" border="1">
  <tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Price</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

i have a popup page where i have a table with multiple checkbox.When the user select any of the checkbox and clicked on button that particular row has to be saved from popup page to parent page
[image]

```
  <script>
 $("table tr").click(function() {

var items=[];
var tablerow = $(this).closest("tr").clone();

var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

   alert("Your data is: " + $.trim(tableData[0]) + " , " +   $.trim(tableData[1]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[2]));

                $(tablerow).children("td:last").html(tableData);
                items.push(tablerow);
                alert(items);
               tablerow.appendTo($("#printTable"));
       });
      </script>
```

[image]

Comment: where is your 2nd table. share the complete HTML

Comment: yeah i have updated my HTML table also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');

$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

     if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').html();
      $('.table2 tbody').append('<tr>'+row+'</tr>');
    } 
   else
   {
    $('#row').find('input:checkbox[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').closest('tr').remove();
 
  }
  $('#row').on('click', ':checkbox', function (event) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="col-md-6">

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;  </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <table class="table1 table table-bordered" id="echo">
      <h3 style="text-align: center;"></h3>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td name="echo">A</td>
 <td>1500</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="check-box"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td id="2">2</td>
 <td name="fetal_echo">B</td>
 <td>2000</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="check-box"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td id="1">3</td>
 <td value="abc">C</td>
 <td>8500</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="check-box"></td>
 </tr>
 <p id="output"></p>
 </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closebtn">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
 <table class="table2 table table-bordered" id="row">
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <div>
```

@vijay mishra and @Vishnu Bhadoriya thankyou for your support....You are really awesome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to map all the data, you can just clone the `tr` and append it to the other table. Like so:

```
<script>
    $("table tr").click(function () {

        // If you don't use a tbody, remove 'tbody' here
        $("#printTable tbody").append($(this).clone());

    });
</script>
```

Comment: yeah but the user will be selecting in the popup page and hence i have to dispplay the content when clicked on button in parent  page

Comment: If the OP doesn't use a `<tbody>` the browser will insert one regardless.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Used loop instead repeating**

Probably not the best answer, but this can insert the value into the second table regardless to the column sorting.

https://jsfiddle.net/o4copkrz/2/

```
$("#input tr").click(function(){

   var $this = $(this)
   var arrIndex = ["id", "name", "price"]
   var arrData = []
   for (var i = 0; i < arrIndex.length; i++) {
     arrData[arrIndex[i]] = $this.find("[data-" + arrIndex[i] + "]").text()
   }

   var $clone = $("#output thead tr").clone()

   for (var i = 0; i < arrIndex.length; i++) {
     $clone.find("[data-" + arrIndex[i] + "]").text(arrData[arrIndex[i]])
     arrIndex[i]
   };

   $clone.appendTo($("#output tbody"))

})
```

Comment: Yeah when i click on checkbox only that selected row has to be displayed..but here for each clicked the table row is being inserted

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h3>First clone the row by clicking on row, then click on button to add to another table</h3>
<table id="firstTable">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Select</th>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
<td>1</td>
<td>Comp</td>
<td>2000</td>
<td class="removeIt"><input type="checkbox" name="rowSelect" class="selectCheck"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
<td>2</td>
<td>mouse</td>
<td>3000</td>
<td class="removeIt"><input type="checkbox" name="rowSelect" class="selectCheck"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
<button id="appendToTable">Append to table</button>
<table id="printTable">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="clonedData" style="display: none;"></div>

<script>
   $(".selectCheck").click(function() {
      if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
         $("#clonedData").append($(this).parent().parent().clone());
         $("#clonedData").find(".removeIt").remove();
      }else{
         var rowCheck = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
         rowCheck.children(".removeIt").remove();
         $('#clonedData tr').each(function(){
           if(rowCheck.html()==$(this).html()){
             $(this).remove();
           } 
         });
       }
 });

 $("#appendToTable").click(function() {
    $("#printTable").append($("#clonedData").children().clone());
    $("#clonedData").html('');
 });
```

I have also created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kgbet3et/11/ for the same. Please check if it adresses your issue.

Comment: yeah the cloning will be added to the same page right. i want to add that  data to parent page from popup

Comment: I am going to update it, you can create a div in hidden mode where you can add cloned element on click of checkbox and then add it to appropriate table on click of button.

Comment: Updated the fiddle and answer.

Comment: yeah this is the way i want but how can i display only the selected checkbox row

Comment: This code is showing only selected checkbox row. If you wish to remove the row on uncheck you can write that in else part of condition. On deselect remove it from div element.

Comment: Write this in else section 
var rowCheck = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
   rowCheck.children(".removeIt").remove();
   $('#clonedData tr').each(function(){
     if(rowCheck.html()==$(this).html()){
      $(this).remove();
     } 
   });